# Бот не видит команду

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, disnake

```
from disnake.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all())

class SelectGame(disnake.ui.Select):
    def __init__():
        options = [
            disnake.SelectOption(label='Counter-Strike: Global Offensive', value = 'id_role'),
            disnake.SelectOption(label='Dota 2', value = 'id_role'),
            disnake.SelectOption(label='Minecraft', value = 'id_role'),
            disnake.SelectOption(label='Valorant', value = 'id_role')
        ]
        super().__init__(placeholder='Выберете игры', options=options, custom_id = 'games', min_values=0, max_values=4)

    async def callback(self, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        await inter.response.defer()
        all_roles = {id_role, id_role, id_role, id_role}
        to_remove = []
        to_add = []

        if not inter.values:
            for role_id in all_roles:
                role = inter.guild.get_role(role_id)
                to_remove.append(role)

            await inter.author.remove_roles(*to_remove, reason='Remove all roles')
        
        else:
            chosen_roles = {int(value) for value in inter.values}
            ids_to_remove = all_roles - chosen_roles

            for role_id in ids_to_remove:
                role = inter.guild.get_role(role_id)
                to_add.append(role)

            await inter.author.remove_roles(*to_remove, reason='Removed roles')
            await inter.author.add_roles(*to_add, reason='Added roles')
class GameRoles(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        view = disnake.ui.View(timeout = None)
        view.add_item(SelectGame())


    @bot.command()
    async def games(inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction):
        view = GameRoles()
        await inter.response.send_message('Выберете роли', view=view)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(GameRoles())

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Хочу сделать SelectMenu для выбора игровых ролей на сервере, но почему-то бот не даёт мне его вызвать, вроде как всё правильно написал, но бот не видит команды !games.

Так же бот не распознаёт `ctx`, я не понимаю почему...